# Unresolved External Symbol C++

Tags: c++

I need to use sockets from winsok2.h. So, I written a class NetObject to use it. But, when I do compilation I am getting an error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall wsa::NetObject::connect(void)" (?connect@NetObject@wsa@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
```

I do this using Visual C++ compiler.

Here is some code:

```
//wsa.h
#ifndef WSA_H_
#define WSA_H_

#include <winsock2.h>

namespace wsa {

sockaddr_in init(const int, const char *, const int);
sockaddr_in init(const int, const char *);
SOCKET init(const int, const int, const int);

class NetObject {
private:
    SOCKET sock;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int check(const int);
public:
    NetObject
        (
            const int addr_family,
            const int sock_type,
            const int protocol,
            const char * ip_addr,
            const int port
        ): sock(init(addr_family, sock_type, protocol)),
           addr(init(addr_family, ip_addr, port)) {};
    int connect();
};
}

#endif //WSA_H_

//wsa.cpp
#include "wsa.h"
#include <winsock2.h>

namespace wsa {

sockaddr_in init(const int af, const char * ip_addr) {
    sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = af;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr);
    return addr;
}

sockaddr_in init(const int af, const char * ip_addr, const int port) {
    sockaddr_in addr = init(af, ip_addr);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    return addr;
}

SOCKET init
    (
        const int af,
        const int type,
        const int protocol
    ) {

    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(af, type, protocol);
    while (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (closesocket(s) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        s = socket(af, type, protocol);
    }
    return s;
}

inline int NetObject::check(const int code) {
    if (code == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (closesocket(sock) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return 1;
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    return 0;
}

inline int NetObject::connect() {
    int res = ::connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    return check(res);
}   
}

//main.cpp
#include "wsa.h"
#include <winsock2.h>

const int af       = AF_INET;
const int type     = SOCK_STREAM;
const int protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    WSADATA ws;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &ws) == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    wsa::NetObject server(af, type, protocol, argv[1], 80);
    server.connect();
    WSACleanup();
}
```

I can't see any errors. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because in Visual Studio, including `winsock2.h` to your headers is not enough. You have to tell the Linker your project will need the library `wsock32.lib`.

You can do that either by editing the properties of your project, or by including this line to your code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
```